# Grails 3.2.9, JDK 1.8.0_73, Spring Security Core 3.1.2 Plugin

Tags: spring-security, grails3

I made a mistake and added the following to BootStrap.groovy:

```
new RequestMap(url: '/', configAttribute: ("ADMIN_GROUP, SUPER_USER_GROUP")).save()
```

This, on Grails startup, predictably, created the error:

Error parsing expression 'ADMIN_GROUP, SUPER_USER_GROUP': EL1041E: After parsing a valid expression, there is still more data in the expression: 'comma(,)'

Reading the doc, I realized the configAttribute needs to be prefaced with ROLE_. So I changed it to:

```
new RequestMap(url: '/', configAttribute: 'ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_SUPER_USER').save()
```

I got the same parsing error on Grails startup.

I then REMOVED ALL CODE from init, and STILL GET the parsing error on startup.

I then added springSecurityService.clearCachedRequestmaps() to init, same problem. 
I'm unable to run the project.

Answer (score 0):

configAttribute: ("ADMIN_GROUP, SUPER_USER_GROUP") had made it into the database. `ReflectionUtils.loadAllRequestmaps()`stumbled over it on Grails startup. Deleted that row from the database, works now.